# a word for algebraic symmetry

Tags: word-request, mathematics, terminology

There is the algebraic expression a+b+c. If we replace under the rule {a->b, b->c, c->a}, the expression is left unchanged. But for expressions like 2a+b+c, the replacement will change the expression. What is the word to describe this kind of symmetry? Thanks

Comment: Is there any term in English? Or you are looking for an algebraic jargon?

Comment: I suggest that this asks for a term of art and belongs on [math.SE].

Comment: If f(x,y,z) = f(y,z,x), then f(x,y,z) is a [**cyclic expression**](http://atozmath.com/Help/HCyclicExpression.htm).

Comment: @DamkerngT. - I think you should make that an answer, because I think that **is** the answer.

Comment: @StoneyB - I just checked the help pages at the [mathematics.se], and I don't think this question would be a good fit for their site. It doesn't seem like it would be [on-topic](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there.

Comment: @J.R. Hmm ... they seem to have quite a few similar [questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) on the **terminology** tag.

Comment: @Stoney - All of those strike me as more specialized than this question. The O.P. here is certainly welcome to delete the question here and ask it there, but I don't want to migrate it, as I suspect it may not be well-received.

Comment: @J.R. Well, Damkerng T. has supplied a responsive comment. If he elects to post it as answer we will have to hope there is somebody around competent to upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term for it is **Cyclic Expressions**.

I just found a good page that explains **[Symmetric and Cyclic Expressions](http://kwiznet.com/p/takeQuiz.php?ChapterID=10888&CurriculumID=48&Num=6.9)**. According to the page,

> An expression f(x,y,z) is said to be a cyclic expression if f(x,y,z) = f(y,z,x).